# Jenkins Promoted Build Parameter Value

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

I have a jenkins job that runs some tests and promotes the build if all tests pass.

I then have a second job that has a 'Promoted build parameter' which is used for deployments.

THe idea is that the deply job should let you pick one of the prompted builds for deploying. The issue I'm having is that I can pick a promoted build, but I have not idea how I access  information about the build.

I've named the build parameter

```
SELECTED_BUILD
```

And according to the docs this should then be available via the environment.
The problem is that it doesn't seem to be bound to anything.

If I run a build step to exectute this sheel script:

```
echo $SELECTED_BUILD
echo ${SELECTED_BUILD}
```

The values are not interpolated / set.

Any idea how I can access the values of this param?

Many Thanks,

Vackar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject the information as variable user jenkins plugin (eject evn variable).

while triggering parameterized build on other job, pass above variable as parameter to next job.